# How to block already used emails in most basic newsletter react/firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It's just a script that sends email to firestore db, I don't know how to check for repeated emials in db.
Code:

```
const Newsletter = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(input) {
      console.log(input);
      addDoc(collection(db, 'emails'),{
        email: input,
        time: Timestamp.now(),
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to avoid that two Firestore documents of the `emails` collection contain the same value for their `email` field. One possible approach is to use a [`Transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.transaction).

Since you are using React and the JS SDK you cannot use a Query in your Transaction. So you need to maintain another collection in which you store one document for each existing email address, **with the email address as the ID of the document**.

This way you can use a code like the following (untested):

```
import { runTransaction, ... } from "firebase/firestore";

try {
  const emailToBeSaved = ....;  // The new email
  await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
    const emailDocRef = doc(db, 'existingEmails', emailToBeSaved);

    const emailDoc = await transaction.get(emailDocRef);
    if (emailDoc.exists()) {
      throw 'This email is already present in the DB';
    }
 
    transaction
    .set(doc(db, 'existingEmails', emailToBeSaved),
       {
        email: emailToBeSaved
       }) // The value of this last parameter is not important, it could be {foo: "bar"}
    .set(doc(collection(db, 'emails')),
       {
        email: emailToBeSaved,
        time: Timestamp.now(),
      })

  });
  console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
}
```

So, we check, in the Transaction if a doc with ID =  emailToBeSaved exists in the `existingEmails` collection.

- If yes, we throw an error.
- If no, we create this doc in the `existingEmails` collection (with dummy data, we are just interested by the ID of the document, not its content) and we add the doc in the `emails` collection. These two writes being done in the Transaction.

---

Note that you could simplify the approach by using the email values as the ID of the documents in the `emails` collection. This way, no need to have an extra `existingEmails` collection.

Comment: It makes sense but when I try to make it 1:1 like this it gives me error with: Unexpected word 'await'

Comment: This is because you need to include this in an `async` function. Most of the Firebase methods are asynchronous: so you need to use the `async`/`await` keywords or Promises with `then()`. See https://javascript.info/async-await and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function